# Ansible jinja2 stop removing escaped double quote

Tags: ansible, jinja2

defaults/main.yml

```
my_var: "[\"test\"]"
```

Then I render this in one template like `template.j2`

```
MY_VARS="{{ my_var }}"
```

```
- name: "create .env from template"
  template:
    src: "templates/template.j2"
    dest: ".env"
```

Result of rendering is:

```
MY_VARS="["d"]"
```

Is there a way to stop replacing `\"` with `"` by ansible?

Expected result of template rendering is:

```
MY_VARS="[\"d\"]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
my_var: "[\"test\"]"
```

to:

```
my_var: "[\\\"test\\\"]"
```

**OR:**

You can use the following as the template:(this is not tested)

```
MY_VARS="{{ my_var|tojson|regex_replace('^\\\"|\\\"$','') }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [single-quotated style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097). Quoting:

| ... the “\” and “"” characters may be freely used.

```yaml
my_var: '[\"test\"]'
```

This is the only change needed. Your code works fine

```yaml
shell> cat .env
MY_VARS="[\"test\"]"
```